# How to test a Rack::Directory serving static files with Capybara? or How to test Rack Middleware with Capybara?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sinatra, cucumber, capybara, rack

I'm using Rack::Directory.new to map a directory in the public folder directly to the website and serve static files.

My config.ru contains:

```
map '/pdfs/' do
  run Rack::Directory.new('./public/resources/pdfs')
end
require './app/main.rb'
   run MainSinatra
```

I'm using a Sinatra App to run the rest of the application and using **cucumber-sinatra** to pre-generate some files.

When I try to load the path to the pdfs in my paths file I get an error.
features/support/paths.rb:

```
def path_to(page_name)
  case page_name    
  when /dias_all/
    '/pdfs'
  ...
end
```

Then on my steps file I put

```
visit dias_all
```

and I get a 404 error.

I tried adding this to the features/support/env.rb file but still got an error:

```
  class MainSinatraWorld
  ...
    include Rack::Test::Methods
    def app
      Rack::Directory.new('./public/resources/pdfs')
    end
  end
```

and then changed the step file visit to a get, but still got an error.

```
 get('/pdfs/dias')
```

error:

```
  No response yet. Request a page first. (Rack::Test::Error)
```

How do I test the contents of the folder through Capybara or Cucumber?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to figure out how to solve this problem by changing this line in env.rb from:

```
Capybara.app = MainSinatra
```

to:

```
Capybara.app = eval "Rack::Builder.new {( " + File.read(File.dirname(__FILE__) +
'/../../config.ru') + "\n )}"
```

And this runs the application from the rack up file (config.ru) and loads all the middleware that wasn't otherwise loading.

I found the answer in this [blog](http://techwhizbang.com/tag/capybara/).